# Alternatives to wrist rest with gel

Tags: ergonomics

I had some wrist rest filled with gel but soon enough they started to deform and become more of a distress than something comfortable. One even leaked a lot of gel in my table and it was a bit messy to clean up.

Is there any comfortable alternatives or even wrist gel brands that are good enough to last for over a year in good condition?

Comment: Solution: get a foam wrist-rest.